# Doubt in proof of Uniform Continuity Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-continuity

I was reading Strichartz' The Way of Analysis, there he proves the Uniform Continuity Theorem:

> Let $f$ be a function 
>   on a compact domain $D$ that is continuous. Then it is uniformly
>   continuous.
>
> Proof : Suppose $f$ is not uniformly continuous, that is, there exists $1/m$ such 
>   that for all $1/n$ there exists two points $x_n,y_n$ in the domain such that 
>   $|x_n - y_n| < 1/n$ but $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| \ge 1/m$.  Since $D$ is assumed compact, the obvious first step is to replace the 
>   sequences $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots$ and $y_1,y_2,y_3,\dots$ by convergent subsequences.The 
>   condition $|x_n-y_n|\le 1/n$ implies that both subsequences converge 
>   to the same limit, call it $x_0$.  Calling the subsequences $x'_1,x'_2,x'_3,\dots$ and $y'_1,y'_2,y'_3,\dots$ we have $|f(x'_n)-f(y'_n)|\ge 1/m$ and yet both $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x'_n)=f(x_0) $ and $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} f(y'_n)=f(y_0) $ by the continuity of $f$ at the point 
>   $x_0$. This is a contradiction; we cannot have $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} (f(x'_n)-f(y'_n))=f(x_0)-f(x_0)=0 $ and $|f(x'_n)-f(y'_n)|\ge 1/m$ for all $n$. 
>    QED

I cannot understand why convergent subsequences of $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots$ and $y_1,y_2,y_3,\dots$ will have the same limits: Sequences $\{x_n\}=5,1,0,1,0,1,0,\dots$ and $\{y_n\}=6,1,0,1,0,1,0,\dots$ have the property that $|x_n-y_n|\le 1/n$ for all $n$ but convergent subsequence $1,1,1,\dots$ of $x_n$ and convergent subsequence $0,0,0,\dots$ of $y_n$ have different limits.

Comment: You need to take the corresponding subsequences: $x_n'=x_{\phi(n)}$ and $y_n'=y_{\phi(n)}$.

Comment: Aha, thank you, I should think that!